# How do I access object attributes that contain special characters?

Tags: javascript

How do I access object attributes whose name contains a number and dot and spaces?

my REST API response is:

```
{
  "Global Quote": {
    "01. symbol": "WDI.FRK",
    "02. open": "147.5000",
    "03. high": "150.1000",
    "04. low": "130.3000",
    "05. price": "139.7500",
    "06. volume": "79625",
    "07. latest trading day": "2019-05-31",
    "08. previous close": "154.0000",
    "09. change": "-14.2500",
    "10. change percent": "-9.2532%"
  }
}
```

This notation does not work:

```
  var data                  = response;
  var price= data.Global%x20Quote.05.%x20price;
```

Comment: Use brackets and a quoted string : `jsonResp["Global Quote"]`

Comment: @JaredSmith, that's an answer, not a comment.  Care to write one?

Comment: @wyck I knew it was a dupe but I'm on my phone and was being lazy. Since you did the work, I've voted to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work: `const price = data['Global Quote']['05. price']`

Comment: You are welcome, hope it helped, if this solved your problem, please accept this answer!

Answer (score 0):

User square brackets, like this

```
 var data = data['Global Quote']['05. price']
```